# Design & selection of Saturn V for Apollo mission

Tags: apollo-program, saturn-v

While the Saturn project evolved out of von Braun's efforts to develop more and more powerful rockets to launch heavier payloads into space for the military, Saturn V, it seems was specifically designed and manufactured to launch the Apollo series of spacecrafts. I am trying to verify and establish a direct, documented link/relation, between the designing, manufacturing and selection of "Saturn V" for the Apollo project. I have read/browsed through many books on Apollo and Saturn evolution, like "stages to Saturn", "Chariots for Apollo", etc. but was unable to find one. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @Ludo:This would give me more information on the subject, once I go through the links provided therein. I will certainly study the same. Thanks.

Comment: Also [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59602/20987) to [How and who calculated the thrust required from first stage of launch vehicle Saturn V for moon landing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59597/how-and-who-calculated-the-thrust-required-from-first-stage-of-launch-vehicle-sa) has a lot of relevant information to this (very similar) question. Basically, Apollo was a justification for the development of heavy boosters, and once the mission was determined, Saturn V was tailored to that in an interplay between CM, LM and Saturn designs teams.

Comment: As Stages For Saturn explains, the Saturn series was to be a family of modular boosters for different missions. During the early planning of the Apollo moon-landing project, the choice was between direct ascent using a very large Saturn C-8, or Earth orbit rendezvous using a couple of C-2 or C-3 boosters. When lunar orbit rendezvous with a single launcher was selected, the Saturn program focused on the C-4 proposal; that grew into the C-5 design with 4 F-1 engines on the first stage, and a 5th engine got added as the payload requirement increased. That version of the C-5 became the Saturn V.